# I have an onEdit() trigger in my sheet that calls a script, but when I copy the sheet for another user the trigger is gone

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

the following is the script that is triggered by any edit

```
function changeSpeadsheetName() {
    
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var range = sheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(7, 1).getValue(); 
   //assuming you want to add the string in A1 to your title
  
   var name = sheet.rename(range);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What are you coping, a spreadsheet or a sheet? How I you doing the copy?

Answer (score 0):

### It looks like you have an [Installed trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) on this script

I can tell this because the name of the function is not `onEdit`. If it was the name of the function, it would likely be a [Simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), but it could also be an installed trigger.

In a nutshell, simple triggers can be copied with the sheet and it will work "out the box". However, they are very restricted and so, this is why your sheet probably has an installed one.

To install the trigger on the new sheet, you need to open the script editor. Once you are at the editing screen, to the left, click on the triggers icon.

[image]

Once there, you can:

[image]

It will ask you what function you want to run when the trigger is triggered, and what type of trigger you want it to be (choose onEdit) - then it will likely ask for authorization, which you should grant.

#### For more details:

- [Simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)